# How to log something in ArangoDB Foxx Test?

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I'm currently testing Foxx service in ArangoDB : https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/develop/foxx-microservices/guides/testing-foxx-services/

In order to help debugging i want to log the response body. I tried to use console.log  :

```
describe('test of action service', function(){
    it('should return 200 on diagnostic', function(){
        const response = request.get(baseUrl+'/action/diagnostic');
        console.log(response.body);
        expect(response.status).to.equal(200);
    });
});
```

but when i launch my tests it doesn't seems to work. Did i miss something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `console.log()` ends up in the ArangoDB server logfile. So if you previously configured logging in the `etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`:

```
[log]
file = /var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log
```

You should find the logfile `/var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log` on your disk.

So, invoking:

```
console.log("hello log");
```

will write this into `/var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log`:

```
2019-02-25T13:20:47Z [87753] INFO hello log
```

You should be able to do similar for the `response.body` - maybe you want to try:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

to get the output of the complete serialized object.